# The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Person', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart, null

Currently I'm working on a small login - like page, the this error shows up all the time:

The return type 'Null' isn't a 'Person', as required by the closure's context.

**mainscreen.dart**

```
import 'api.dart';
import 'person.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key, required person}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<List<Person>> _futurePersons = Api.getPersons();

  void _login() async {
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    try {
      final persons = await _futurePersons;

      final currentUser = persons.firstWhere(
        (person) => person.name == username,
        orElse: () => null,
      );

      if (currentUser != null) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Szia, ${currentUser.name}!'),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text('A te ID-d ${currentUser.id}'),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                Text('A felhasznalok'),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: persons.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(persons[index].name);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        // If the user is not found, show an error message
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Error'),
            content: Text('User not found in database'),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle errors, e.g. show a dialog or a snackbar
      print('Error finding user: $e');
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),
          content: Text('Failed to find user'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: _usernameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Username',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _passwordController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              child: Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**person.dart**

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class Person {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Person({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Person(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      name: json['name'] as String,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }

  factory Person.newPerson(String name) {
    return Person(
      id: Uuid().v4(),
      name: name,
    );
  }

  static Person getDefault() {
    return Person(id: "", name: "");
  }

  void add(Person person) {}
}
```

Can you guys please help me?

I've tried chatgpt, tried to modify the codes on different parts but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`persons` is `List<Person>`, non-nullable items on list, Therefore it can't return null from `orElse`. You can use different approach like `.indexWhere`, it will return negative index when it fails to find an item.

```dart
final currentUserIndex = persons.indexWhere(
  (person) => person.name == username,
);
final currentUser = currentUserIndex > -1 ? persons[currentUserIndex] : null;
```